# Use import dependencies

Tags: angular, webpack

I added some dependencies to my project, but the feature is not appearing.
Ex: MetisMenu.js, -> it is inside my node_modules but when I use the elements it appears as if it did not.
With jquery-slimscroll it was the same thing.
to try to escape this problem, I copied inside a folder lib o .js and in my module I am doing:
require("../lib/metisMenu.js");

but I have many dependencies, where and how would it be right?

Comment: please be more specific, also post relevant part of your code

Comment: ok, I added MetisMenu to the project dependencies. And I use a .js that uses metisMenu. I'm importing this js using require, like this:   require("lib/inspinia.js");
My inspinia.js use $('#side-menu').metisMenu(); but a have $(...).metisMenu is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
<script src="lib/metisMenu.js"></script>
```

to your index.html file in your project root folder